# Pass table cells textlabel data to array in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass table cell's `textLabel` data of `UITableViewController` to `NSArray`. Those cell have `identifier` name `Cells` and accessory type `checkmark`

Comment: Please include what you have tried

Comment: Tried my best to fix some of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Code that does exactly what you asked is here:

```
func getCellsData() -> [String] {
    var dataArray: [String] = []
    for section in 0 ..< self.tableView.numberOfSections() {
        for row in 0 ..< self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
            if cell.reuseIdentifier == "Cells" && cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {
                dataArray.append(cell.textLabel!.text!)
            }
        }
    }
    return dataArray
}
```

But I would like to recommend you find different approach, because this is the rude traverse of `tableView`. You probably have your `dataSource` model that can give you ll data you need. Additionally, this code doesn't check for errors, for example if there is no text in `cell` at some `indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Two things I'd advise.

First, looks like you're using the checkmark accessory to indicate multiple selections. It's really intended for single selection, like a radio button. Better to use the `allowMultipleSelections`option on the tableview. This will allow...

...the second thing. Copying text from cells into an array is the wrong way round to do it. Better to ask the table view and call it's `- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows` this will give you an array of index paths to selected cells then you can ask for each cell and grab any data you want from it. This gives you better live data and prevents you unknowingly creating a circular reference from the view controller of the tableview and the content in the tableview cells.